# How to quote a shell script command?

Tags: shell, quotes

I am trying to form a parametric call to curl from a shell script

```
header_string="--header \"X-param1: 1\" --header \"X-param2: 2\""
url="http://example.com"
command="curl $header_string $url"

a=`${command}`
```

This does not work because it is interpreted like

```
curl --header '"X-param1:' '1"' --header '"X-param2:' '2"' http://example.com
```

How can I quote this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using BASH you can make good use of BASH arrays:

```
header_string=(--header "X-param1: 1" --header "X-param2: 2")
url="http://example.com"
command="$(curl -s "${header_string[@]}" "$url")"
```

But if you're using old `sh` then use of dreaded `eval`:

```
header_string="--header \"X-param1: 1\" --header \"X-param2: 2\""
url="http://example.com"
command=`eval "curl $header_string $url"`
```

Comment: Nice (ab)use of `eval`. +1.

Comment: Preferred way is to use BASH and avoid `eval` :)